# Trigger event not opening correct modal with PHP variables

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a global modal `#global-modal` defined in `footer.php`.

If an `anchor` tag has the class `modal__trigger`, then it will find the `data-video` on that element and open it in a modal. This works fine.

However, I now have another modal which will require the use PHP variables.

For demo purposes, I will refer to...

- Modal 1 as `iframe modal`
- Modal 2 as `experience modal`

Because I require the use of PHP variables, I have `<script>` defined in the `php` file and in that script, I have the JS variable required that holds the `experience modal` code.

However, at the moment, even though the event trigger is different, it will always show the `iframe modal`.

- `footer.php`: Is where the `#global-modal` code is found.
- `modal.js`: Is where the JS is found that opens the modal
- `experience.php`: Is where the `experience modal` and PHP vars is defined.

In short, when a user clicks `modal__trigger`, it should show the `iframe modal` and when a user clicks the `experience__trigger`, show the `experience modal`.

`footer.php`

```html
<div class="modal" id="global-modal">
  <div class="modal__inner">
    <a class="modal__close"></a>
    <div class="modal__box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`modal.js`

```js
(function($) {

  $(document).on("click", '.modal__trigger', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var modalID = '#global-modal';
    $('.modal').removeClass('modal--open');

    $(modalID).fadeIn(200,function(){
      $(this).addClass('modal--open');
    });

    var url = $(this).attr('data-video');
    
    var htm = '<a href="#" class="modal__close"></a><div class="modal__wrapper"><iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+ url + '?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe></div><div class="modal__overlay"></div>';
    $(modalID).html(htm);

    return false;

  });

  $(document).on("click", '.modal__close,.modal, .modal__overlay,.modal__background,.modal__pattern', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var modalID = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
    $(modalID).fadeOut(200,function(){
      $(this).html('');
      $(this).removeClass('modal--open');
    });

  });

})(jQuery);
```

`experience.php`

```html
<?php $string = "this is a string"; ?>

<a class="experience__trigger">
  Click me for experience modal
</a>


<script>
(function($) {
  $(document).on("click", '.experience__trigger', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var modalID = '#global-modal';
    $('.modal').removeClass('modal--open');

    $(modalID).fadeIn(200,function(){
      $(this).addClass('modal--open');
    });

    var experience_html =
      '<a href="#" class="modal__close"></a>' +
      '<div class="modal__wrapper">'+
        '<div class="container">'+ $string +'</div>'+
      '</div>'+
      '<div class="modal__overlay"></div>'+
      '<div class="modal__pattern"></div>'+
      '<div class="modal__background"></div>
    ';

    $(modalID).html(experience_html);
    return false;

  });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: You can't just include PHP inside JavaScript code like that, they're two different languages. . But anyway why do you think this needs a PHP variable? The $string variable is just hard coded anyway, it's not like it depends on some calculation which can only be done on the server.

Comment: It's possible you have an error in your console due to an undefined variable, or something like that. Did you check?

Comment: @ADyson - `$string` just a dummy variable, what I actually have is bunch of `get_field` variables as I'm pulling content from ACF to display in the `experience modal`

Comment: @ADyson - I've checked console and no errors

Comment: ok have you used your JS debugger (and/or some simple console logging) to check the value of `experience_html` before you run `$(modalID).html(experience_html);`? Have you checked that this code definitely executes?